# bug on bounds in OpenCV cv2.seamlessClone

Tags: python, opencv

There is a bug on mask bounds in `cv2.seamlessClone`. It produces on mask filled with 255 only on edges.
Does anyone new how to solve it?
Now I ignore images when I need to blend only edges.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

background = np.zeros((100, 100, 3)).astype(np.uint8)
target_object = np.ones_like(background).astype(np.uint8) * 255
mask = np.zeros_like(target_object)
bound = -1
mask[:, bound:] = 255
center = (mask.shape[0] // 2, mask.shape[1] // 2)
cv2.seamlessClone(target_object, background, mask, center, flags = cv2.NORMAL_CLONE)

# bound:
# -1, -2 : "terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::length_error'
#   what():  vector::_M_default_append"
# -3 : "cv2.error: OpenCV(4.0.0) /io/opencv/modules/core/src/matrix_wrap.cpp:1669: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !fixedSize() in function 'release'"
# <= -4 : works
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've opened issue for this bug in opencv
https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/15294
As workaround for your issue i suggest manually add 1 pixel on borders.